# symbolic computation with any number of symbolic parameters. How to Simplify them?

Tags: linear-algebra, symbolic

I want to define d×d matrix $A$ as $A_{mn} = \exp{[\sum_{i=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^n \theta_{ij}]}$. Here $\theta_{ij} $ is real numbers. I wrote below script in Mathematica 12.

```
d = 3; Clear[A]; Clear[theta]
Array[A, {d, d}]; Array[theta, {d, d}];
For[m = 0, m < d, m++, {
    For[n = 0, n < d, n++, {
      A[m, n] = E[Sum[theta[i, j], {i, 0, m}, {j, 0, n}]]
      }]}];
mtx = Table[A[i, j], {i, 0, d-1}, {j, 0, d-1}];
mtx // MatrixForm
```

The Purpose of my script is getting $\rm{det}[A]$.

```
Det[mtx]
```

How can I simplify it?

```
Det[mtx] // FullSimplify
```

I think I should use assumpution of $\theta_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$. But I do not know how to do it.

Comment: How could you write `Array[A, {n, n}]; Array[theta, {n, n}];` when `n` is not defined? `Array[A, {n, n}]` gives error. You did not get an error on your Mathematica? Your sum is also wrong `Sum[theta[i, j], {0, i, m}, {0, j, n}]` you can't use zero as summation index. May be you meant `Sum[theta[i, j], {i, 0, m}, {j, 0, n}]`  It is better to evaluate each code one by one to see the problems easily. You also have `m++ {` which is wrong.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @Nasser Thank you for your comment. I fixed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = 3;
Clear[A]; Clear[theta]
Array[A, {d, d}]; Array[theta, {d, d}];
For[m = 0, m < d, m++,
  For[n = 0, n < d, n++,
   A[m, n] = Exp[Sum[theta[i, j], {i, 0, m}, {j, 0, n}]]
   ]
  ];
(mat = Table[A[i, j], {i, 0, d - 1}, {j, 0, d - 1}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Dimensions[mat]
(* {3, 3} *)

Det[mat] // Simplify
```

[image]